# Saving Tokens Error: Core Dump

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, token

I wrote this code in C to save a few fields of a string of values so that I may call them again for a formatted output, yet the code seams to fail after the first field is taken - Segmentation fault (core dumped).
I made sure to free the allocated memory after using it but it doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char* getfield(char* line, int num)
{
    const char* tok;
    for (tok = strtok(line, ";");
            tok && *tok;
            tok = strtok(NULL, ";\n"))
    {
        if (!--num)
            return tok;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE* stream = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    char line[1024];
    while (fgets(line, 1024, stream))
    {
        char* tmp = strdup(line);
        char* save1 = malloc(sizeof(char)*51);
        strcpy(save1, getfield(tmp, 1));
        printf("Save1 = %s\n", save1);
        strcpy(save1, getfield(tmp, 2));
        printf("Save2 = %s\n", save2);
        free(save2);
        char* save2 = malloc(sizeof(char)*51);
        strcpy(save2, getfield(tmp, 2));
        printf("Save2 = %s\n", save2);
        free(save2);
        char* save3 = malloc(sizeof(char)*51);
        strcpy(save3, getfield(tmp, 3));
        printf("Save3 = %s\n", save3);
        free(save3);
        char* save4 = malloc(sizeof(char)*51);
        strcpy(save4, getfield(tmp, 4));
        printf("Save4 = %s\n", save4);
        free(save4);
        char* save5 = malloc(sizeof(char)*51);
        strcpy(save5, getfield(tmp, 5));
        printf("Save5 = %s\n", save5);
        free(save5);

        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

Again, only the first field in a line seems to work fine.
Here's the example file used:

```
1;Matt;LeBlanc;Friends;1994         
2;Matthew;Perry;Friends;1994
3;Michael;Hall;Dexter;2006
4;Judy;Greer;Archer;2009
5;Justin;Roiland;RickAndMorty;2013
```

My output looks like this

```
Save1 = 0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

But if I amend the code so that only save1 is used then the output is this

```
Save1 = 0
Save1 = 1
Save1 = 2
Save1 = 3    
Save1 = 4
Save1 = 5
```

Comment: Don't dual tag C code as C and C++.  Your code can't be C++; the `malloc()` calls are missing the cast that is necessary in C++ and unnecessary in C.  And add 4 lines to your code — three `#include` lines and one blank line — to complete the code.  The information should be in the question, not a comment.

Comment: Don't forget that `strtok()` butchers your string.  It's chopped it up.  You can't usefully use it the way you're trying to.  It is likely that `strcpy(save1, getfield(tmp, 2));` causes the core dump because `getfield()` returns a NULL pointer, which `strcpy()` then tries to use.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, thank you for informing me. This is the first question I have posted in this website and I was unsure of what to tag.

Comment: `getfield` will not work as you expect.

Comment: Your approach need `strdup` each call it. E.g `tmp = strdup(line); ... strcpy(saveN, getfield(tmp, N)); free(tmp);`

Comment: fix like [this](http://ideone.com/i2viFQ)